# Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Statement(s) could not be prepared. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
    F.NidLog, F.NidFormReport , ltrim(rtrim(F.Caption)), F.NidTask, 
    F.NidUser, F.UserName, F.ActionState, F.ActionDate, F.ActionTime, 
    W.NidProc, W.WorkflowTitel, W.BizCode, W.NidWorkItem, T.TaskTitel
from 
    openquery([192.168.12.69], '(select * from Esup..TaskLog) as F
                                inner join Esup..Task as T on T.NidTask  = F.NidTask
                                inner join Esup..WorkflowInstance as W on T.NidProc = W.NidProc')
```

After I execute the query shown above, I get this error:

> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: Try removing parentheses from `(select * from Esup..TaskLog)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax is `OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )`

Removed 2 brackets

```
from openquery ([192.168.12.69] , 'select * from Esup..TaskLog  as F 
inner join   Esup..Task as T on T.NidTask=F.NidTask
inner join  Esup..WorkflowInstance as W on T.NidProc=W.NidProc' )
```